# ctrl + enter seems not working with UIKeyCommand

Tags: ios, enter, ctrl, uikeycommand

I am trying to interfere with the external hardware keyboard's inputs on an iOS system.

Everything works well except for one problem: After attempt to register <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> with code

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [.control], action:...)
```

press the combination won't trigger the action, which means it seems not to register itself. However, `"\r" + [.command]` and `"\r" + [.alternate]` work well.

What's wrong with it? How can I register <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from the external keyboard?